# ESP32-CAM stream in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, esp32

I am using AI Thinker ESP32-CAM with stream url `http://192.168.8.100:81/stream`.
I have tried this and other techniques but nothing worked for me

```
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.8.100:81/stream")

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried `http` as well instead of `rstp` but no results at all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have used this arduino code

```
#include <esp32cam.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* WIFI_SSID = "ZONG MBB-E5573-AE26";
const char* WIFI_PASS = "58688303";

WebServer server(80);

static auto loRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(320, 240);
static auto hiRes = esp32cam::Resolution::find(800, 600);

void handleBmp()
{
  if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(loRes)) {
    Serial.println("SET-LO-RES FAIL");
  }

  auto frame = esp32cam::capture();
  if (frame == nullptr) {
    Serial.println("CAPTURE FAIL");
    server.send(503, "", "");
    return;
  }
  Serial.printf("CAPTURE OK %dx%d %db\n", frame->getWidth(), frame->getHeight(),
                static_cast<int>(frame->size()));

  if (!frame->toBmp()) {
    Serial.println("CONVERT FAIL");
    server.send(503, "", "");
    return;
  }
  Serial.printf("CONVERT OK %dx%d %db\n", frame->getWidth(), frame->getHeight(),
                static_cast<int>(frame->size()));

  server.setContentLength(frame->size());
  server.send(200, "image/bmp");
  WiFiClient client = server.client();
  frame->writeTo(client);
}

void serveJpg()
{
  auto frame = esp32cam::capture();
  if (frame == nullptr) {
    Serial.println("CAPTURE FAIL");
    server.send(503, "", "");
    return;
  }
  Serial.printf("CAPTURE OK %dx%d %db\n", frame->getWidth(), frame->getHeight(),
                static_cast<int>(frame->size()));

  server.setContentLength(frame->size());
  server.send(200, "image/jpeg");
  WiFiClient client = server.client();
  frame->writeTo(client);
}

void handleJpgLo()
{
  if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(loRes)) {
    Serial.println("SET-LO-RES FAIL");
  }
  serveJpg();
}

void handleJpgHi()
{
  if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(hiRes)) {
    Serial.println("SET-HI-RES FAIL");
  }
  serveJpg();
}

void handleJpg()
{
  server.sendHeader("Location", "/cam-hi.jpg");
  server.send(302, "", "");
}

void handleMjpeg()
{
  if (!esp32cam::Camera.changeResolution(hiRes)) {
    Serial.println("SET-HI-RES FAIL");
  }

  Serial.println("STREAM BEGIN");
  WiFiClient client = server.client();
  auto startTime = millis();
  int res = esp32cam::Camera.streamMjpeg(client);
  if (res <= 0) {
    Serial.printf("STREAM ERROR %d\n", res);
    return;
  }
  auto duration = millis() - startTime;
  Serial.printf("STREAM END %dfrm %0.2ffps\n", res, 1000.0 * res / duration);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  {
    using namespace esp32cam;
    Config cfg;
    cfg.setPins(pins::AiThinker);
    cfg.setResolution(hiRes);
    cfg.setBufferCount(2);
    cfg.setJpeg(80);

    bool ok = Camera.begin(cfg);
    Serial.println(ok ? "CAMERA OK" : "CAMERA FAIL");
  }

  WiFi.persistent(false);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }

  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("  /cam.bmp");
  Serial.println("  /cam-lo.jpg");
  Serial.println("  /cam-hi.jpg");
  Serial.println("  /cam.mjpeg");

  server.on("/cam.bmp", handleBmp);
  server.on("/cam-lo.jpg", handleJpgLo);
  server.on("/cam-hi.jpg", handleJpgHi);
  server.on("/cam.jpg", handleJpg);
  server.on("/cam.mjpeg", handleMjpeg);

  server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  server.handleClient();
}
```

And OpenCV code

```
import urllib
import cv2
import numpy as np

url='http://192.168.8.100/cam-hi.jpg'

while True:
    imgResp=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    imgNp=np.array(bytearray(imgResp.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
    img=cv2.imdecode(imgNp,-1)

    # all the opencv processing is done here
    cv2.imshow('test',img)
    if ord('q')==cv2.waitKey(10):
        exit(0)
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks for this answer. I am glad I found this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
import cv2
from urllib.request import urlopen
import numpy as np

url = r'http://192.168.43.236/capture'
while True:
    img_resp = urlopen(url)
    imgnp = np.asarray(bytearray(img_resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    img = cv2.imdecode(imgnp, -1)
    cv2.imshow("Camera", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 113:
        break
```

If you use the url ".../stream", the response for that is never ending and will continue, but if you send a capture request it will give you a reasonable size output.